# Why didn't Fiona have that "True love's kiss" special effects in Shrek: Forever After?

Tags: shrek

Do you guys remember when Fiona's permanent Ogre figure was activated by Shrek's kiss in *Shrek*? It had that amazing transformation effect! see:

[image: Fiona's Ogre transformation effects]

<sup>[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIP1Z.jpg)</sup>

In *Shrek: Forever After*, why was it passive?

Comment: A plot hole, I would think.

Comment: Because different directors do things differently.

Comment: It's not especially clear in the novelisation, but if I had to guess it would be because she's already *inside*  a much more powerful enchantment. When the kiss finally works (at the start of the day when she doesn't become a princess), the bigger spell is broken and a much more violent effect occurs.

Comment: I'm confused by the down votes -- this is a valid question, no?

Answer (score -2):

The magic of True Love's Kiss is only applicable the first time around:

> Princess Fiona: But... how will you kiss me?
>
> Shrek: [bangs his head] What? That wasn't in the job description!
>
> The Donkey: Maybe it's a perk!
>
> Princess Fiona: No, it's destiny! You must know how it goes! The Knight rescues the
> Princess, and then they share true love's *first* kiss...

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0002001/quotes)

Comment: In Rumpelstiltskin's timeline, it's actually the first time they kiss.